# Never having p.p. vs. Having never p.p.?

Tags: word-order, participle-clauses

Recently I have encountered 'Having not p.p.', which puts ***not*** between having and p.p.

In fact, I was taught to put ***not*** before having p.p.
And *BBC Learning English* confirms it.  Which is the definite grammar rule?

> Negative participle clauses are also possible, in which case ***not***
> normally comes before the -ing form or past participle:
>
> *Not having had a shower for two days, I was desperate to get to the
> bathroom.*

[BBC Learning English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv305.shtml)

Comment: "Normally" does not mean the same as "always".

Answer (score 1):

The BBC guidance describes the most usual form; it does not give a rule. 'Not having *done something*' and 'Having not *done something*' are equivalent and there is no 'rule' that says the first is correct and the second incorrect. You can negate the verb phrase (not [having *done something*]) or the direct object (having not *done something*).